# SimpleXMLIterator isn't showing children

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm having a problem with the `SimpleXMLIterator` and descending through an xml structure. I broke it down into it's simplest form for this post:

```
<?php

$string = <<<'XML'
<test>
    <group>
        <script>
        </script>
    </group>
</test>
XML;

$iterator = new SimpleXMLIterator($string);

for($iterator->rewind() ; $iterator->valid() ; $iterator->next()){
    echo $iterator->key() . "<br>";
}
```

I would expect that the code above would output:

```
group
script
```

but when I run it, it only outputs `group`.

When I move the xml so that group and script are siblings:

```
<?php

$string = <<<'XML'
<test>
    <group>
    </group>
    <script>
    </script>
</test>
XML;

$iterator = new SimpleXMLIterator($string);

for($iterator->rewind() ; $iterator->valid() ; $iterator->next()){
    echo $iterator->key();
}
```

I get both group and script echoed out.

I've been reading through the documentation on the iterator and I don't see anything that says it doesn't descend to children. Am I misunderstanding the tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second xml with both nodes are on the same level. The first however has the first node and the second node is inside therefore is not traversed. So you need to recursively traverse it.

You can use `RecursiveIteratorIterator` in this case:

```
$string = <<<'XML'
<test>
    <group>
        <script>
        </script>
    </group>
</test>
XML;


$xmliterator = new SimpleXMLIterator($string);
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($xmliterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
for($iterator->rewind() ; $iterator->valid() ; $iterator->next()){
    echo $iterator->key() . "<br>";
}
```